Which characters are alive as of the end of the series?
Obviously, this question contains major spoilers for the second and so far final season of Arcane.



 Viktor and Jayce are sucked into the wild rune anomaly from Ekko's Z drive.




Heimerdinger mysteriously disappears while helping Ekko escape an alternate universe.




 Jinx seemingly blows herself up, but Caitlyn seems to think there is a possibility that she faked her death, and we are shown a balloon and an ending frame that hint toward that possibility.




 Warwick (Vander) also seemingly is blown up with her, but he is very tough and can regenerate.




 Ambessa is attacked by LeBlanc, but Mel pulls her out. We do see Mel in command of her forces later, something that Ambessa would never allow.




 We see someone or something that looks like Sky talking to Viktor, who seemingly disappears when he attains his final form.



There are a lot of situations here that, on first viewing, may be somewhat ambiguous, but could be resolved by details or comments from the writers.
Which champions (and other characters) are alive as of the end of the second season of Arcane, and which are not?
